# Proof: Every convergent sequence of real numbers is bounded

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

> (Taken from an old exam - no homework:)
>
> Prove that every convergent sequence of real numbers is bounded.

It would be cruel if our professor would take a task like that in the exam because I rather prefer calculating than doing theory (in an exam where you haven't got much time to describe things..). But I'll be honest and say I dislike theory in general! :-)

Anyway, for the task, I really got no idea how to proof that but I'll give it a try...

---

We know that if a sequence is convergent it has exactly ONE limit where the sequences (sry my English here) accumulate. So the sequence will have an upper bound or lower bound, based on the limit, thus it will be surely bounded if it's convergent sequence.

---

Even if my proof is wrong (most likely..) I'd like to see a proof like mine, where you avoid using (complicated) maths symbols. Just using words any human can understand would be awesome! :-)

Of course a more formal proof is welcome too but not necessarily preferred ^.^

Comment: Mathematics has its own language, and it's beautiful. Use it ;)

Comment: Your proof isn't a proof because all you've done is restate the hypothesis and declare that this implies the sequence has upper and lower bounds. How do you conclude that the upper and lower bounds exist?

Comment: Why does havent a limit mean an upper or lower bound? the limit need not be either.  100, -50, 25,-13,6.5, -3.25, ....  converges to 0.  So is neither the upper bound nor the lower bound.

Comment: From what I read [in the tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-explanation/info), I understand that (proof-explanation) is supposed to be used if you have a prove from somewhere and need an explanation of some parts of it. For checking, critiquing, suggesting improvements to your own proof [the tag proof-verification](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-verification/info) seems to be more suitable. (So if you want use one of the tags with the proof- prefix, this would be the one.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The basic idea is:

1. Any finite set of real numbers is bounded.
2. The tail of the sequence is bounded by the limit plus/minus epsilon from some point onwards.

So you can divide it into a finite set of the first say $N-1$ elements of the sequence and a bounded set of the tail from $N$ onwards. Each of those will be bounded by 1. and 2. above. The conclusion follows.

---

If this helps, perhaps you could even show the effort to rephrase this approach into a formal proof forcing yourself to apply the proper mathematical language with epsilon-delta definitions and all that? Post it as an answer to your own question ...

Comment: Let $(x_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence which is convergent and let $x$ be its limit. Then there is a $n \in N$ with $|x_{n}-x|<1$ for all $n \geq n_{0}$. When we use on this triangle inequality we have $|x_{n}|-|x| \leq ||x_{n}|-|x|| \leq |x_{n}-x| < 1$. Thus $|x_{n}| < 1+|x|$ for all $n \geq n_{0}$. If we now set $M= max\{|x_{0}|, |x_{1}|,.. |x_{n_{0}}|, |x| +1\}$. Then finally we have for all $n$ that $|x_{n}|\leq$ $M$ so $(x_{n})$ is bounded by this $M$?

Comment: @tenepolis: Looks good to me :o)

Comment: @cnmesr: Perhaps, depending on the character of the exam! I usually tell my students that techniques central to the type of question they are answering should be precise and detailed while techniques that are merely simpler or more peripheral steps can be suppressed. It seems central here, though, to demonstrate familiarity with the formal machinery and mathematical language. When would otherwise be the time to acquire that?

Comment: Yeah you are totally right.. But you know it's different for me I try to do this as easy as I can, the theory. Maths is really fun but not if it comes to theory and explanations. I study computer science, made up of 3 real maths modules (one is analysis) and I just want pass them, not understand every single thing for now (I'm not lazy but my brain has its limits : /). But really thanks a lot for everything you wrote here it's awesome!

Comment: @cnmesr: OK, that's cool! I get that! I think that it works both ways. Formal language is a tool to avoid mistakes your intuition might make, but having intuition is a great thing, nonetheless. It is like an overview-detail relationship. The optimal situation is to master both.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, let's start off with the definition of a convergent sequence:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n}=a  \Leftrightarrow (\forall \varepsilon>0)(\exists n_{0} \in \mathbb{N})(\forall n > n_{0}) |a_{n}-a|<\varepsilon$$
What this definition states is that after a certain term of a sequence, all the following terms will be close to the limit.

Now, we can take an arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$ and for that $\varepsilon$ we know that all the terms of the sequence whose index is greater than $n_{0}(\varepsilon)$ are in the interval $(a-\varepsilon , a+\varepsilon )$. So **almost all** of the sequence is bounded. What about $a_{0}, a_{1}, ... , a_{n_{0}}$? Well, there's a finite number of them, so we can choose a minimal and a maximal element, and denote them as $A$ and $B$, respectively.

Now, it's apparent that the sequence is bounded, because all of its terms are in the interval $[\min\{A, a-\varepsilon \}, \max\{B, a+\varepsilon\}]$.
I hope the proof was clear enough.

Comment: Thank you very much too ! :-)

Comment: Thank you very much!....