# We know $a_n = \frac{1}{n-1}$ converges to zero, but is it bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am having some trouble grasping the statement "Every convergent sequence must be bounded". Although the proof has been [explained here before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1958543), and I understand some part of it, I cannot quite grasp why a sequence like $a_n = \frac{1}{n-1}$ is bounded. Obviously $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n) = 0$, but $a_n$ is undefined for $n=1$. Does this not imply that $a_n$ is not bounded (above), because there exists no $M$ such that $\frac{1}{0}<M$?

Comment: the sequence a_n is only defined for n>=2, for  these n it is bounded (e.g. by 1)

Comment: Oh, that makes total sense. Thanks for the rapid response!